# Need to pass array value in to another array

Tags: laravel-9

```
   $dataOrder = [
  'orderid' => date( 'ymdhis' )
   ];


                $details =[

         
                'orderid'=>$dataOrder->orderid



               ];
```

I need to pass $dataOrder array's orderid value into  $details array. And error is "Attempt to read property "orderid" on array". This code is for testing purpose.

Answer (score 1):

change `$dataOrder->orderid` to `$dataOrder['orderid']`

by the way,
you can do this:

```
$dataOrder = date( 'ymdhis' );

$details = [
      'orderid'=>$dataOrder
 ];
```